# R replace string-matching in dataframe with value from another dataframe/array

Tags: r

I created a code to match string value from a different and if matched replace the string value with the later

I have one data frame and other is array where in first

```
df1 <- data.frame(campaign_source=c("googleadwords", "google display" ,"twitter banner", "facebook-post", "facebook like","inmobi","organic"),cost=c(4,2,3,4,5,6,7))

source<-c("google","facebook","twitter")
```

The objective is to create a new column in df1 which should have value based on any text matching df1$campaign_source with source so I used

```
df1$n_campaign_source<-"other"   

    for (k in 1:nrow(df1))
{
  for(i in 1:length(source)){
    h<-df1[k,]$campaign_source
    h1<-df1[k,]$n_campaign_source
    j <- grep(source[i],h )
    if(is.na(j[1]) == FALSE & h1 !='other'){
      df1[k,]$n_campaign_source<-source[i]
    }
  }}
```

This one is taking lot of time , Any faster solution is appreciated
final-output

```
no campaign_source cost n_campaign_source
1  googleadwords    4            google
2  google display    2            google
3  twitter banner    3          facebook
4   facebook-post    4          facebook
5   facebook like    5           twitter
6          inmobi    6             other
7         organic    7             other
```

Answer (score 1):

(The answer above appears incorrect.) Try this alternate code that uses the `grep` result as an index for assignment:

```
 df1$source <- NA
 for( item in source ) df1$source[grep(item,  df1$campaign_source)] <- item
 df1$source[is.na(df1$source)] <- "other"
 df1
#-----------------
  campaign_source cost   source
1  google adwords    4   google
2  google display    2   google
3  twitter banner    3  twitter
4   facebook post    4 facebook
5   facebook like    5 facebook
6          inmobi    6    other
7         organic    7    other
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using `strsplit`:

```
df1$source <- sapply(df1$campaign_source, function(x) {
    w <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " "));
    if (length(w[w %in% source]) > 0) w[w %in% source] else "other";
})
#campaign_source cost   source
#1  google adwords    4   google
#2  google display    2   google
#3  twitter banner    3  twitter
#4   facebook post    4 facebook
#5   facebook like    5 facebook
#6          inmobi    6    other
#7         organic    7    other
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- data.frame(campaign_source=c("google adwords", "google display" ,"twitter banner", "facebook post", "facebook like","inmobi","organic"),cost=c(4,2,3,4,5,6,7))

source<-c("google", "facebook", "twitter");
```

Comment: Hi Maurits, thanks for your help .sometimes the text in df1$campaign_source is not space separated, the text could be "googleadwords" or "facebook-new-user"

Comment: @SaugataHalder I see; unfortunately your sample data didn't mention those cases. I was trying to provide a solution without explicitly looping through the entries in `source`. Never mind, 42-'s solution will still work for you.

Comment: yes  @Maurits its a great help from your side anyway, I just thought of mentioning the use case